# GIF not fullscreen safari

Tags: html, css, formatting, background-image

I am displaying a gif in the background of my react app & need it to take up the entire screen, regardless of screen size, browser, etc. It's working perfectly on chrome, but not on safari (cuts off mid-screen). This is a pretty big formatting problem as this version is currently in production. How can I get the gif to format properly?

**CSS:**

```
.myGradientBackground {
   background-image: url('my_gif.gif');
   background-size:100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Looks okay at first glance. Maybe we need more context?

Comment: @Chipster I'm not sure there's much more to give, I have an html `div` with this class name as the parent view and on chrome it shows perfectly (the entire  background on mobile is this image), that's really the entire thing.

Comment: try background-size:cover it that helps.

Comment: @SumitPatel that cuts it off at it's true height, I want to extend the entire size of the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work

```
.myGradientBackground {
    background: url('my_gif.gif') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    background-size: cover;
}
```